# $H_{k+1}(X \cup_f D^{k+1},X) = ?$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am stuck with the calculation of the following homology group: $H_{k+1}(X \cup_f D^{k+1},X) = ?$ where $X$ is a simply-connected CW complex and $f: S^k \to X$ is a continuous map (attaching map of the disk).  How should I compute it?  Would the final answer depend on the topology of $f$?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: many thanks for the hint!  But last time what you suggested for a variant of this question is to use Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  Which one (Mayer-Vietoris or excision?) would you recommend?  I am actually not very sure that excision theorem applies not matter what map $f$ is!

Comment: Actually, you could also just use $H_{k+1}(X \cup_f D^{k+1},X)\cong H_{k+1}((X \cup_f D^{k+1})/X)$. Can you identify what the quotient space is? (it doesn't depend on $f$)